# MySQL pivot with multiple counts

Tags: php, mysql, pivot

This is a snapshot of my MySQL table:

[image]

Is it possible to write a query to get such a pivot table like output...

[image]

Comment: can you have a text format of your records instead of screenshot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `CASE` statement on this to pivot your table.

```
SELECT  url_host,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN post_ID = -1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) Negative_One,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN post_ID = 0 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) Zero,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN post_ID > 0 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) Greater_Zero
FROM tableName
GROUP BY url_host
```

## [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/aa679/1)

Comment: Gave it to @astander as that was the first reply. Thanks guys!

Comment: @AkshayRaje really? hover our time and see the difference. :D

Comment: @astander it was just a typo error, i was thinking of `sum` but i wrote `count` that's why in the `else` i also wrote `0`. any way, the OP is FREE to change the check mark. no hurt feelings as I am not perfect. :D

Answer (score 3):

How about something like

```
SELECT url_host,
    SUM(CASE WHEN post_id = -1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as post_id_minus1,
    SUM(CASE WHEN post_id = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as post_id_0,
    etc...
FROM    YOUR_TABLE
GROUP BY url_host
```