# Group MySQL results with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am having the following script that takes the results from 3 tables based on a field called "order_id" in all tables.

```
$sql = "SELECT 
o.order_id, 
order_product.model,
o.name, 
o.value, 
GROUP_CONCAT(o.order_id, order_product.model, o.name, o.value SEPARATOR ',') AS Options 
FROM `order_option` AS o 
LEFT JOIN `order` AS oo on o.order_id = oo.order_id
LEFT JOIN order_product ON o.order_id = order_product.order_id
where oo.order_status_id = 2 
group by oo.order_id";

$result = mysql_query($sql); 
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
 {
$options=$row['Options'];
print "|$options|";

    PRINT "<br>-------------------<br>";
}
```

The problem is that in table "order_option" there are 2 or more rows with options for each order_id.

**The results printed by the script is:**

> ID, Model, option1:Value, ***ID, Model,*** option2:Value

**And what I need is:**

> ID, MODEL, OPTION1:Value, OPTION2:Value

So, no duplication of ID and MODEL for every row.

Any suggestions how can I achieve that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL pivot with multiple counts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12652309/mysql-pivot-with-multiple-counts)

Comment: same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14767984/how-to-combine-two-mysql-columns-to-one-column-in-php/14768092#14768092

Comment: Just remove all the columns from `GROUP_CONCAT()` except `name,value`, and print `$row['order_id'], $row['model']` in addition to just printing `$options`.

Comment: Attn dupe closevoters - please read before voting.  The linked question is completely unrelated.

Comment: Indeed, I needed help with the PHP part of the script not the query itself. Both links are related to the query.

@ Michael Berkowski, thanks... your advice worked well!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with how you're implementing `GROUP_CONCAT`.  You have 2 rows in your `Order_Option` table that have different options with the same option id.  Something like:

```
OrderId    Name     Value
1          Option1  Value1 
1          Option2  Value2
```

Using GROUP_CONCAT(OrderId, Name, Value) will concatenate all those fields like:

```
1, Option1, Value1, 1, Option2, Value2
```

Instead, you want to retrieve your OrderId on it's own:

```
SELECT OrderId, GROUP_CONCAT(Name, Value)...
```

This will give you:

```
1, Option1, Value1, Option2, Value2
```

And then the rest is just in your presentation logic.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I need. Just as Michael stated.